# Change format date (varchar) in SQLite table

Tags: regex, sqlite, date

I have a big table in SQLite with a field for dates (varchar type) with a following format dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm (i.e. 01-01-2014 01:20) and I need to transform them into the following format dd-mm-yyyy, hh:mm (adding a comma after year i.e. 01-01-2014, 01:20)

How can I do this? Does it exist any way with date formatter or using regexp in SQLite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply want to insert something after the tenth character.
Use the [substr function](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#substr) for this:

```
UPDATE BigTable SET AField = substr(AField, 1, 10) || ',' || substr(AField, 11)
```